# C#, am I using StreamReader wrong?

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

Alright. So the issue is, I'm trying to pick a random line on a certain file and assign it to a string variable. It's for whatever reason not letting me use StreamReader to read the line, how do I fix this and is there any reason as to why this is happening?

My code

[image]

The error I get

[image]

Comment: *`for whatever reason`* VS is telling you *exactly* what that reason is.  So, yes you are using it wrong.  You are also using this site wrong - do not post pictures of code or pictures of errors.  Paste them here.  Visit the [help] and read [ask] for more on using the site effectively.

Comment: Please copy/paste *text* - screenshots are discouraged on SO.  ALSO: If you're already calling File.ReadLines(), then why re-read the file with StreamReader?  Just 1) Read all the lines into a variable, 2) fetch a random line with .ElementAt()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's solve the problem in *general case*. We don't know file length (number of lines) so we can't
use `Random.Next(length)` comfortably (reading the entire file *twice* - once to obtain file length and then to get random line in not a good option) but we can use [reservoire sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling):

```
private static T RandomElement<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Random random) {
  if (source is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

  if (random is null)
    random = new Random();

  T result = default(T);
  int count = 0;

  foreach (var item in source)
    if (random.Next(++count) == 0)
      result = item;

  return count > 0
    ? result
    : throw new ArgumentException("Empty sequence doesn't have random element", 
                                   nameof(source));
}
```

Then we can use our routine for our file:

```
Random random = new Random();  

...

string path = @"c:\MyFile.txt";

string randomLine = RandomElement(File.ReadLines(path), random);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReadLine` doesn't take a number as an argument, [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=net-6.0). If you want to read a specific line, you'll have to read all the lines up to and including that line.

Comment: Yeahh, I see. I may be quite a newbie at this. Thanks for the links, I've somehow been having trouble finding the proper documentation site for it.

Comment: @Ghost You can't have put much effort into it, when I googled `C# StreamReader` the very first hit was the Microsoft Docs page for the class.